# Setting height with jQuery without refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created 2 divs on top of each other. The first div holds a WordPress generated img and the second div slides in from the top when hovering the image div. In the normal css both divs have a fixed height, but when i add media queries i need to change the height of the image div to auto to maintain the right dimensions.

HTML code:

```
<div class="portfolio-page-thumbnail">
  <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
  <div class="portfolio-page-hover">
        <p>BEKIJK PROJECT</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
     .portfolio-page-thumbnail{
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
     }
     .portfolio-page-hover{
       width: 100%;
       position: absolute;
       top: -50%;
     }
```

Here is the problem: When decreasing my browser width, the image scales just fine, but the hover div stays at a fixed height and because the hover div has an absolute positioning, it cant inherit the height from it's parent.

I created a jQuery snippet to take the height from the image div and set this height to the hover div.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".portfolio-page-hover").height( $(".portfolio-page-thumbnail").height()    );
});
```

And this works fine on refresh, but as soon as I decrease my browser width, this no longer applies and I have to refresh again. Normally this is just fine, but when my client changes from portrait to landscape, it appears broken. 
I'd like to know if there is an solution to set the height 'real time' without refreshing?

Thnx!

Comment: Is `portfolio-page-hover` always meant to be the same height as `portfolio-page-thumbnail`?

Comment: Use `$(window).resize(function() {myFunc()});` where `myFunc()` has `$(".portfolio-page-hover").height( $(".portfolio-page-thumbnail").height());` in it and then add myFunc() to the `$(document).ready(function(){myFunc()});`

Comment: @Andy Yes, they always need to be the same size, width and height

Comment: _“and because the hover div has an absolute positioning, it cant inherit the height from it's parent”_ – why not? That should work fine. (You might want to add `position:relative` to the parent though, if not already set elsewhere, so that it becomes the anchor point for the absolute positioning.)

Comment: @Denzorrr What's the `top: -50%` for?

Comment: @Andy So it starts from the top to bottom. I like to use this over CSS transform/translate(X/Y) for crossbrowser compatibility.

Comment: @CBroe The parent height is set to 'auto' aswell and because giving an element an absolute postion will take it out of the DOM flow.

Comment: _“The parent height is set to 'auto' aswell ”_ – so the image in it will determine its height. And I know absolute positioning takes the element out of flow, but that doesn’t mean you can not have it inherit its height from the parent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could place it inside a `resize` event handler:

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
    $(".portfolio-page-hover").height( $(".portfolio-page-thumbnail").height());
});
```

This will get called whenever the window is re-sized.

Comment: I have found a problem with this snippet. It workes on resizing the screen, but as soon as i refesh, it loses its given height and the default height kicks in..

Comment: Yeah, you would also have it on `ready` as in your code above.

Comment: Ok, i'm relatively new to jQuery, but if I read this function right, it makes sense why it wont work on refresh. When refreshing the page, the DOM loads again, and this function only fires on resize. So when reloading the DOM, this element cant get a height because the window is not resized. Or am I reading it wrong?

Comment: @Denzorrr Yeah that alone will not work on refresh, when the page reloads it may not re-size. That's why it needs to in both `.ready` and `.resize`. In my answer I'm assuming you would add that along with the code you already have. That's why the answer below separates it into the function. So `$(".portfoli...` isn't written twice.

Answer (score 1):

I figured I'd turn my comment into an answer. Same answer as Spencer however it calls a function so you don't have to write it multiple times.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 myFunc();
});

$(window).resize(function(){
 myFunc();
});

function myFunc() {
 $(".portfolio-page-hover").height( $(".portfolio-page-thumbnail").height());
}
```

More information about jQuery's resize event handler [here](https://api.jquery.com/resize/)

Comment: Thnx for your trouble! But his solution worked just fine. Can you explain, for educational reasons, why i have to right his code multiple times? Yours seems longer and his worked. Just Curious :)

Comment: The window `resize` function only fires when the window is resized. The document `ready` function fires when the DOM is ready for js code to execute. Having the code inside the `myFunc()` function and calling the function twice (once from the `resize` function and once from the `ready` function) allows you to manipulate one function (`myFunc()`) instead of rewriting your code for each event being fired. My solution can be used if you want to call the function `myFunc()` multiple times. If you are only going to call it once, ever (say inside the `resize` function but not `ready`, Spencer's ans)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first of all, thnx to all you guys/girls for your help.
I found a solution by combining the above answers.

Result:

```
 // Sets the right height to the Hover element
 function myFunc() {
    $(".portfolio-page-hover").height( $(".portfolio-page-thumbnail").height());
 }

  //Sets the correct height on refresh
  myFunc(); 

  // sets height when resizing the window
  $( window ).resize(function() {
    myFunc();
  });
```

Note: This code will be placed inside another code that allready has a document.ready function.

Is it written the correct way? Or can the code be cleaner?